# Where is the default zsh history file?

Tags: default, zsh, logfile

`HISTFILE` isn't set in my `.zshrc` file.

To which file is zsh history saved by default?

Or, is the history just being stored in memory?

Comment: Is HISTFILE set in your environment? `echo $HISTFILE`

Comment: It is usually ~/.zhistory

Answer (score 30):

> Zsh has no built-in default value for HISTFILE. The zsh distribution
>   comes with a setup wizard for new users which has the value
>   ~/.zsh_history built in...

More by Gilles on [Command history in Zsh - Unix SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/111718/command-history-in-zsh)

Answer (score 4):

For me it was `~/.zsh_history`

You can also check with `echo $HISTFILE`

Comment: ~/`.histfile` for me :-( I'm on Ubuntu, and no, I didn't set `$HISTFILE`.